# Why do I have an error on some Flattr buttons?

Tags: flattr

I've integrated Flattr with my Dotclear blog, using the appropriate plugin, and it works fine.

Except that, from time to time, some older posts have errors and I don't understand why.

See:

http://ploum.net/post/224-gpager-03-scenes-from-a-memory-finally-free

http://ploum.net/post/86-le-repas-de-noel-en-famille

those posts have nothing special and, yet, cannot be Flattered.

Could it be an issue on Flattr side ? Do you see what can cause that problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is disrupted by doublequotes in "var flattr_tle=", you should encode them with '`&quot;`'

Comment: thanks, reported that to the developers. It should fix it. http://lab.dotclear.org/ticket/708

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're both using the new 0.6 version of the Flattr JavaScript API and a quite old 0.2 version. Using two versions at the same page can probably result in some pretty strange things - I would suggest just using the newer version that is documented here: https://flattr.com/support/integrate/js

Regarding why the button show an error - here's a bit of a secret way to find out: Look at the HTML for the button iframe and look within the div-tag with a "button-wrapper"-class - there you should find an HTML-comment that states the reason for the button error.

In your case the HTML-comment in the button iframe says "ERRORS: User couldn't be found and no owner specified." - which isn't strange since the iframe's URL has "0" specified as the uid-parameter - it should be a username instead.