# Flattr buttons display an error using Tumblr theme code

Tags: tumblr, flattr

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605758/why-do-i-have-an-error-on-some-flattr-buttons) also on [my blog](http://mitar.tnode.com/) since few days ago Flattr is displaying error on all buttons. What is wrong? Has something changed the API? I have not changed any code but when I see the blog or any of the posts there there is an big "error" displayed instead of the Flattr button. Is there a way to get a reason why there is an error?

[Here](https://github.com/mitar/mitarpage/blob/master/template.html#L716) you can see the code I am using to generate Flattr buttons. Above in head you can see their JavaScript I am including. Is there an error in my code? Because code worked for some time.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `en_US` locale which [is not supported](https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/languages.txt). I don't know why it worked before but changing to `en_GB` solved the problem. Thanks to [voxpelli](https://github.com/voxpelli) for [pull request](https://github.com/mitar/mitarpage/pull/3) with a fix and explanation.